# Camunda use ExecutionListener on Process Deployment

Tags: bpmn, camunda

How can we externalise our logic from the parseProcess in the BpmnParseListener ?

Is there any way to do the same as executionListener with End event, where we can add a Listener triggered when and EVENTNAME_END is fired ?

example : 
activity.addExecutionListener(ExecutionListener.EVENTNAME_END, progressLoggingExecutionListener);

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the camunda-bpm-reactor extension

It allows you to annotate a listener with @ CamundaSelector and does not require additional custom parse listeners